# Is there any way to determine the type of a mountpoint?

Tags: macos, bash, mount-point

I've got a `bash` script that deals with files in Mac OS X 10.5 & 10.6. It now needs to determine whether the files are on a local volume or a remote AFP volume. All mountpoints are in `/Volumes` on Mac OS X, but I cannot see any difference between local & remote volumes, at least with `ls -al` (except for the boot volume, which is a symlink to `/`).

Is there a way to programatically, esp. something that can be easily called from a `bash` script (I *really* don't want to rewrite this in C/Obj-C with OS X-specific APIs, unless absolutely necessary), to determine the *source* or type of a mountpoint? Even what device a volume maps to (assuming volumes mounted with `mount_afp`, `mount_smbfs`, `mount_webdav`, etc., won't point back to a device in `/dev`) so I have *some* way of guessing whether it's local or not?

Comment: What do you get with `file /Volumes/*`?

Comment: There's nothing special at all about a mountpoint itself, but I suppose you want to find out something about the thing that's mounted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I don't believe there's an API for it that's common across platforms. You could, however parse the output of the `mount` command:

```
~$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Users/nknight (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, nobrowse)
```

`mount` without arguments has roughly the same effect on most *nix-ish systems, though I don't believe the output format is standardized anywhere.

---

I would encourage you to rethink your approach, however. The whole point of network filesystems is that applications aren't supposed to care about them. Consider posting another question explaining what you're trying to accomplish by doing this. Someone can probably offer a superior and more generalized solution.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know and I can definitely parse what I need (the FS type) out of the output. I appreciate the encouragement to rethink my approach, fortunately it's a Mac OS X-specific `bash` script, so I only have to worry about compatibility across Mac OS X releases.

Answer (score 2):

Does the plain

```
$ mount
```

command without any additional args tell you what you need?